# Linq ToList strange behaviour

Tags: c#, linq

Why `List<Component> l = second.ToList();` lead to

> System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe

in `select new { id = b.id, Name = b.Name };`

How to fix this?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Component> firstlist = new List<Component>();
        List<Component> secondlist = new List<Component>();
        List<Component> thirdlist = new List<Component>();

        firstlist.Add(new Component { id = 1, Name = "Jhon" });
        secondlist.Add(new Component { id = 2, Name = "Jhon" });
        thirdlist.Add(new Component { id = 3, Name = "Jhon" });

        var first = from d in firstlist
                                 join i in secondlist
                                 on d.id equals i.id
                                 into a
                                 from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new { id = b.id, Name = b.Name };

        var second = from f in first
                     join s in thirdlist
                     on f.id equals s.id
                     into a
                     from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new Component { id = b.id, Name = b.Name };

        List<Component> l = second.ToList();

    }

    public class Component
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have the line:

```
from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

You're specifically saying that you should use a default value for items in that list if it's empty.  The default value for reference types (which those anonymous objects are) is `null`, and you're dereferencing that value, so you get a NRE.

Answer (score 0):

No equality between firstlist and secondlist, join cannot work ;)